# Return value EOF of scanf in C

Tags: c, eof

Scanf in C language, I am a little confused about the return value.

In the instruction, it says:

1. EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.
2. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream is set.

First, I am not sure what they mean by if the **end of input** is reached **before** the first successful conversion or **before** a matching failure occurs. How is that possible?

Second, I am not sure the difference between read error and matching failure?

Comment: for input from screen,scanf will read data until you press ctrl+z, which is `EOF` but the screen input.

Comment: @YazanWYusuf: That depends what platform you're on... on DOS/Windows, Ctrl+Z will send `EOF`; on Unix-type systems, typically Ctrl+D signals `EOF`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First, I am not sure what they mean by if the end of input is reached before the first successful conversion or before a matching failure occurs. How is that possible?

Imagine you're trying to read a character from a file and you're at the end of the file. The end of input will be reached before any successful conversion or matching attempt takes place.

> Second, I am not sure the difference between read error and matching failure?

A read error means you were unable to read data from the `FILE`. A matching failure means you were able to read data but it didn't match what was expected (for example, reading `a` for `%d`.)

Comment: To add onto David's answer with some examples.  If I have a program that just prints out the return value and stored value (i.e. x) for scanf("%d",&x);... if I do echo "" | ./a.out, I get -1,0 [indicating EOF before matching problem); if I do echo "a" | ./a.out, I get 0,0 [indicating you got data, but it wasn't correct]... if I do echo "1" | ./a.out, I get 1,1 [indicating I got one result and it was 1]

Comment: So read error is something when the given file is not readable by the program? while matching failure is literally not having a corresponding pair?

Answer (score 2):

The function `scanf()` returns the number of fields successfully read and converted. But if I type (Windows) `Ctrl-Z` for the input, that indicates `EOF`. In Linux, I think that may be `Ctrl-D`? So if you haven't entered meaningful values, `scanf()` indicates failure in one way or another.

Typically, you test for the number of inputs required, and this will cover the `EOF` situation too.

```
if (1 != scanf("%d", &i))
    printf ("No valid input\n");
```

Comment: So does the first part mean if I input stop(e.g.Ctrl-Z) instead of expected values, EOF is returned?

Comment: You should experiment. Programming is very much a hands-on experience. Here is the documentation for `scanf()`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1.aspx

Comment: What's the advantage of the style `constant != scanf(...)`? I've seen this two times, while I still can't figure it out.

Comment: @Rainning I don't usually, but it guards against typos when using `==`. For example the mistaken `if(x = 1)` is still valid syntax, but `if(1 = x)` is not, because you can't assign a value to a constant.